# Mini-alignment of a single equation?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath, align

So I have this problem, whereupon I would like to do some 'mini-alignment'. I have googled for ways to do this, but I get results based on aligning whole equations. Here is my current output:

[image]

What I would like to do, is:

- Bring the "11" a little to the left.
- Push the second and third lines a little to the right.

It is those small things that I am not really privy as to how to change. But they make all the difference in the aesthetics.

The code I used was this:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\lefteqn{\mathbf{S}[k,m] \bigl\rvert_{k \neq k_s}  = \overbrace{\bigg[v_R^2[k,m] + v_I^2[k,m] \bigg]} ^{\gamma}  + }   \\
&\begin{rcases}
& \delta[k - k_q]\bigg[ q_R^2[k,m] + q_I^2[k,m] \bigg]  + \nonumber \\
& \delta[k - k_q]\bigg[ 2q_R[k,m]v_R[k,m] + 2q_I[k,m]v_I[k,m]\bigg]
\end{rcases}\footnotesize{g}
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: Please, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: You could probably use the `split` environment or the `empheq` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- [Don't use `eqnarray`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) -- it's severely deprecated. Consider using an `align` environment instead.
- I wouldn't use `\bigg`-sized brackets; `\big` would seem to be perfectly adequate.
- Unless you want the `g` symbol to be perfectly aligned with the equation number in the preceding line, it's probably better *not* to align them at all.
- Rather than make the symbol `g` very small, I'd enlarge the symbol `\gamma` by issuing a `\textstyle` command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{10} % just for this example
\begin{align}
\mathbf{S}[k,m] \big\vert_{k \neq k_s}  
&= \overbrace{\bigl[v_R^2[k,m] + v_I^2[k,m] \bigr]}^{\textstyle\gamma} + \\
&\begin{rcases}
& \delta[k - k_q]\bigl[ q_R^2[k,m] + q_I^2[k,m] \bigr] + \nonumber \\
& \delta[k - k_q]\bigl[ 2q_R[k,m]v_R[k,m] + 2q_I[k,m]v_I[k,m]\bigr]
\end{rcases}g
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico, but I have some questions. I like what you did, but I would like to pull the last two lines of the equation to the left. I would also like to pull the "11" to the left as well. How can I do that?

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond - For the first objective, move the alignment point in the first line from its current location (right before `=`) to, say, right before `\big\vert`. (You didn't say how much the other lines should be shifted, so this suggestion may not be what you're looking to achieve.) The relative position of the equation number is mainly function of the width of the text block and can't be shifted unless you want an entirely different layout.

Comment: Thanks the moving of alignment did it! It also took care of the '11' as well somehow. Very nice. Some follow ups - suppose I wanted to increase the distance between the first line and say the second line. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond - to increase the distance between the first and second line by, say, `2ex`, you'd type `\\[2ex]` at the end of the line instead of "just" \\.

Comment: `\nonumber` should go outside of `rcases`, for instance after `g`. And probably an `aligned` instead of `align` would be better, so the equation number is set midway. Also `rcases` should be `drcases`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `eqnarray` environment; `align` from amsmath gives better vertical spacing and its syntax is simpler. For the number placement, I suppose it's the equation number. One can insert a horizontal space after the equation number with the `\newtagform` command, from `empheq` — within  a certain limit.

Here is a code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtagform{mine}{(}{)\hskip 1.2cm}
\usetagform{mine}

\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text textt text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{align}
\mathbf{S}[k,m] \bigl\rvert_{k \neq k_s} & = \overbrace{\bigg[v_R^2[k,m] + v_I^2[k,m] \bigg]} ^{\gamma} + \\
&\qquad \begin{rcases}
\delta[k - k_q]\bigg[ q_R^2[k,m] + q_I^2[k,m] \bigg] + \\
\delta[k - k_q]\bigg[ 2q_R[k,m]v_R[k,m] + 2q_I[k,m]v_I[k,m]\bigg]
\end{rcases}\footnotesize{g}\notag
\end{align}
Text text text text text text text text textt text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text textt text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

[image]